# Check for IndexedDB 2.0 Support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, indexeddb

What is the best way to programatically check if the browser in which an app is running supports IndexedDB 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [several API changes in IndexedDB 2.0](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/10/whats-new-in-indexeddb-2-0/) so you could do feature detection on any of them. Maybe the easiest would be this:

```
const idb2 = !!IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0).includes;
```

since that doesn't even require creating a database.

However you should be careful, because some browsers may not have supported all of the spec at the same time. Just because they support part of the IndexedDB 2.0 spec doesn't mean they support all of it.

In most situations, I don't think that's a big practical concern. All the major browsers either support all of IndexedDB 2.0 (Chrome/Firefox/Safari) or none of it (IE/Edge), and that's been true for a while now.